# What is the difference between Geb automation tool and Selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium2, test-automation-framework, geb

I just want to know why it is I should go for Geb automation.
What are the advantages of using Geb automation over selenium Web driver or Robot framework.
I would like to know regarding following feature:

1. PageObject support
2. jQuery content selection
3. Good integration with BDD frameworks like Spock, Cucumber etc.

Please describe in detail how these features are beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

Geb runs WebDriver in the [Groovy language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29).  The goal is to make the use of WebDriver simpler.

However, if you use WebDriver directly, [it's supported in a number of languages](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_What_about_support_for_languages_other_than_Java?), including Python, Ruby, C#, Java and implementations exist in others, including PHP, Perl and potentially Javascript.

The support for PageObject and jQuery selection is existent in both, given that they utilise most of the same components.

[How Geb handles PageObjects](http://www.gebish.org/pages).

[Geb's Navigator API](http://www.gebish.org/content), which is inspired by jQuery.

And yes, both have the same degree of integration with Spock etc.

For more information on Geb, check out the [Book of Geb on the official site](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/).